# Perl concatenate

Tags: perl

I'm watching a training video of UDEMY for perl, but the video is not clear and looks like it contains errors.

The training is showing how to concatenate 2 strings with the following example:

```
#!usr/bin/perl

print $str = "Hi";
print $str .= " there\n";
```

However when I run the script it the output is:
**HiHi There**

Where is the second Hi coming from? Am I missing something?

Comment: Printing assignments is not a beginner's subject. IMO, of course. I'd suggest that on this basis you look for a better tutorial.

Comment: There is something else wrong as well: the case of the 't' in 'there' has changed to uppercase.

Answer (score 8):

The first statement assigns the value "Hi" to $str, then prints it. The second statements adds the value " there\n" to $str, making the $str equal to "Hi there\n", then prints it. Thus, the output you're getting is correct for what you're telling the interpreter to do.

Answer (score 7):

If the training really shows this script, ditch it — it's not code that one would normally write.

`$str = "Hi"` sets the variable `$str` to the string `"Hi"`. Most of the time, the value of an assignment is not used, the assignment is only performed for its side effect which is to change the value of the variable. However, in Perl, an assignment does have a value, which is the value that is assigned to the variable. The instruction `print $str = "Hi"` prints the value that is assigned, i.e. this prints the string `"Hi"`.

The second instructions assigns to `$str` the value that consists of the old value of `$str` concatenated with `" there\n"`, i.e. `$str` is set to `"Hi there\n"`. Once again, the value that is assigned is printed, i.e. this prints the string `"Hi there\n"`.

Normally one would not use the value of the assignments:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
my $str = "Hi";
$str .= " there\n";
print $str;
```

Comment: I fixed it like this: #!usr/bin/perl

$str = "Hi";
print $str .= " there\n";

Comment: @frankguthrie it's still poor Perl coding style. Take another look at what you've been offered in this answer. And abandon the "tutorial" you're trying to follow.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but why is the code giving by my by Gilles better then the execution I used? It seems my code contains less lines? So why the anwser Gilles gave the better option?